# Clickhouse not scaling CPU linearly beyond 28 threads

Tags: c++, database, multithreading, analytics, clickhouse

I have Clickhouse version: 20.8.7.15 running on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with 56 physical CPU cores (112 logical cores with HT enabled) and 256 GB RAM.

I created a MergeTree table which has hourly reporting data and i am trying to run a query which aggregates metrics for 15 days of data. I tried running the query with different values for --max_threads option provided by clickhouse.

I started with --max_threads=7 and kept doubling the value (7, 14, 28, 56, 112) and tried to run the same query. My observation is that execution time reduces to nearly half when i doubled the --max_threads value until --max_threads=28, after that execution time for query was greater with --max_threads=56 than with --max_threads=28

Someone please explain to me, why this might be happening. Am is missing something ?

**Table Definition**

```
CREATE TABLE datawarehouse.AggregatedHourly
(
    `vertical_id` UInt8,
    `line_item_id` Int32,
    `campaign_type` UInt8,
    `campaign_id` Int32,
    `creative_id` Int32,
    `creative_type` Int32,
    `enterprise_id` Int32,
    `advertiser_id` Int32,
    `publisher_id` String,
    `exchange_id` Int32,
    `manufacturer_id` Int32,
    `os_id` Int32,
    `os_version_id` Int32,
    `app_id` String,
    `app_bundle_id` String,
    `app_name` String,
    `IabCategoryId1` Int32,
    `IabCategoryId2` Int32,
    `IabCategoryId3` Int32,
    `site_domain` String,
    `user_country_id` Int32,
    `user_carrier_id` Int32,
    `is_wifi_targeted` UInt8,
    `traffic_type` UInt8,
    `zone` UInt8,
    `is_ssl` UInt8,
    `day` Date,
    `hour` UInt8,
    `deal_id` Int32,
    `connection_type` UInt8,
    `billing_type` UInt8,
    `creative_orientation` String,
    `ltv_event_id` Int32,
    `ltv_event_currency` Int32,
    `ltv_is_reengagement` UInt8,
    `conversion_object_id` Int32,
    `session_depth` Int16,
    `model_version_id` Int16,
    `user_state_id` Int32,
    `user_city_id` Int32,
    `is_rewarded` UInt8,
    `is_unknown_device_id` UInt8,
    `model_id` Int32,
    `rtb_creative_id` Int32,
    `d0_day` Date DEFAULT day,
    `d0_hour` UInt8 DEFAULT hour,
    `auction_type` Int8,
    `adhoc` String,
    `requests` Int32,
    `bids` Int32,
    `wins` Int32,
    `unique_wins` Int32,
    `impressions` Int32,
    `unique_impressions` Int32,
    `clicks` Int32,
    `unique_clicks` Int32,
    `installs` Int32,
    `unique_installs` Int32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY (day, hour, vertical_id)
ORDER BY (enterprise_id)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    multiIf(auction_type = 1, 'First Price', auction_type = 2, 'Second Price', auction_type = 0, 'NA', 'Unknown') AS optimization_auction_type,
    SUM(unique_wins) AS result_wins,
    SUM(unique_impressions) AS result_impressions,
    SUM(unique_clicks) AS result_clicks,
    SUM(unique_installs) AS result_mmp_click_installs
FROM datawarehouse.AggregatedHourly
WHERE ((day >= '2020-11-01') AND (day <= '2020-11-15')) AND (enterprise_id IN (10049))
GROUP BY optimization_auction_type
```

| Threads | Execution Time (in seconds) |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 52.001 |
| 14 | 27.205 |
| 28 | 15.511 |
| 56 | 16.886 |
| 112 | 25.444 |

Clickhouse is reading 13.77 billion rows while executing the query.

[Clickhouse Trace logs on execution of query with 28 and 56 threads](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/files/5830112/ch_query_execution_trace.log)

Comment: I've faced the same situtation months ago but as far as I remember, if you exceed 28 threads, then you can actually send the same query twice and ClickHouse will use the rest of the CPU power to run the second query, therefore, it helps for running multiple queries in the same time. I'm not asserting that this is a design choice, but this is how I wrapped my head around it. My guess is that it tries to avoid context switching between 2 different query processes.

Comment: I know this question is quite old, but OP might be getting IO blocked. Remember that, besides the CPU and RAM, the speed of the query depends on your storage (except if you are using Memory engine). It may be that past 28 threads, you're saturating your HDD / SSD IO and they can't provide data fast enough. With more than 28 threads, some of your threads have to wait for data before doing any meaningful work, thus making query time greater.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are being limited by disk bandwidth, are the disks fast? Are they under load? Check the metrics for disk if you can.